# CGridview filter by dropdown using related model

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, yii, cgridview

I have two tables : User and UserProfile both are in relations. i.e UserProfile belongs to User. User table has column "is_active" which stores the active/inactive record of particular user in 0 and 1 format.

Now I have one dropdown field which contains options Active (value 1) and Inactive (value 0) and I want to filter CGridview widget according to active and inactive users list.

Following is what I am doing:

```
<?php echo CHtml::dropDownList('UserProfile[is_active]', $model->user->is_active, 
  array(
    '1'=>"Active",
    '0'=>"Inactive",
  ), array('onchange'=>"$.fn.yiiGridView.update('yw0', {data: $(this).serialize()});") ); ?>

<?php
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView', array(    
    'type' => 'striped bordered condensed',
    'dataProvider' => $model->search(),
    'filter' => $model,
    'template' => '{pager}{items}',
    'enableSorting' => true,
    'columns' => array(
        'title.name',
        array(
            'name' => 'first_name',
            'type' => 'raw',
            'value' => 'CHtml::link($data->first_name,"/userProfile/$data->user_profile_id")'
        ),
        'last_name',
        'user.username',
        'user.email',        
        array(
            'class' => 'bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonColumn',
            'template' => '{update}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{delete}',
        ),
    ),
    'pager' => array(
        'header' => '',
        'hiddenPageCssClass' => 'disabled',
        'maxButtonCount' => 3,
        'cssFile' => false,
        'class' => 'CLinkPager',
        'prevPageLabel' => '<i class="icon-chevron-left"></i>',
        'nextPageLabel' => '<i class="icon-chevron-right"></i>',
        'firstPageLabel' => 'First',
        'lastPageLabel' => 'Last',
    ),
    'pagerCssClass' => 'pagination',
));
?>
```

Controller:

```
public function actionManage() {

        $model = new UserProfile('search');        
        $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values

        if (isset($_GET['UserProfile'])) {            
            $model->attributes = $_GET['UserProfile'];
        }

        $this->render('manage', array(
            'model' => $model,
        ));
    }
```

And here is my Search method:

```
public function search() {

        $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
        $criteria->compare('first_name', $this->first_name, true);
        $criteria->compare('middle_name', $this->middle_name, true);
        $criteria->compare('last_name', $this->last_name, true);
        $criteria->with = array('user');
        $criteria->join = 'LEFT JOIN AuthAssignment ON AuthAssignment.userid=user_id';
        if (isset($_GET['employee'])):
            $criteria->addCondition("AuthAssignment.itemname <> 'Customer'");
            $criteria->addCondition("user.is_active='$status'");
        else:
            $criteria->addCondition("AuthAssignment.itemname = 'Customer'");
            $criteria->addCondition("user.is_active='$status'");
        endif;

        //Rights::getAssignedRoles(Yii::app()->session['user_id']);

        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria' => $criteria,
            'pagination' => array(
                'pageSize' => 10,
            ),
        ));
    }
```

Here I want `$status` variable value to be dynamic as dropdown field change active or inactive.

and when change dropdown option its showing following error:

```
TypeError: settings is undefined
$grid.addClass(settings.loadingClass);
```

I am newbie in Yii and need help on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

first declare a property user_status in profile model

like

```
public $user_status;
```

Then in the search method of profile model

```
$criteria->with = array( 'user' );
$criteria->compare( 'user.is_active', $this->user_status, true );

return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
      'criteria'=>$criteria,
      'sort'=>array(
        'attributes'=>array(
          'user_status'=>array(
            'asc'=>'user.is_active',
            'desc'=>'user.is_active DESC',
          ),
          '*',
        ),
      )
    ));
```

Then in the profile gridview inside the columns array

add

```
array(
      'name'=>'user_status',
      'header' => 'Status',
      'value'=>'$data->user->is_active',
      'filter' => array( '1'=>"Active",'0'=>"Inactive" )
      'type' => 'raw',
    ),
```

No need to have that chtml dropdown

Comment: Its showing dropdown field with active and inactive option but the functionality is not working

Comment: Don't forget to add `user_status` attribute as safe (on search scenario) in your model's rules

Comment: @soju: When I am clicking on selecting value from dropdown its showing ajax error : `TypeError: settings is undefined
[Break On This Error]  

$grid.addClass(settings.loadingClass);`

Comment: i have updated the code with 'type' => 'raw' this might solve

Comment: i think it is a jquery conflict problem

Comment: @Neophile: What is the issue?